# parseInt seems to be wrong

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal, radix, parseint

i want to convert a number from decimal to binary, and i instantly remembered that parseInt also has a base argument, and just to be sure, i ran the following code:

```js
parseInt('123', 2);
```

and the output was... 1?

after that I checked developer mozzila, and the second argument WAS the base, then I tried base 3, and the output was 5!!!!! this shouldn't be possible in base 3!

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: `parseInt('123', 10)`

Comment: `parseInt` parses the string until the first invalid character. "2" is an invalid character base 2.

Comment: the digits 2 and 3 are meaningless for base-2 numbers

Comment: Also, `'123'` is not a number; it's a string. If you want a binary equivalent, convert `'123'` to a plain JavaScript number, and then use `.toString(2)` to get your binary equivalent (as another string).

Comment: both of the answers are correct and useful... what do i do??? i cant mark both of them as correct

Answer (score 2):

The radix argument represents the radix of the input number not output number.

```
parseInt('1111', 2); // returns 15
```

### From [MDN parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> ```
> parseInt(string, radix)
> ```
>
> **radix**
>
> An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in
> mathematical numeral systems) of the string.

Comment: `parseInt('1111011', 2)`

Answer (score 2):

The output is ALWAYS an integer. If you really want to use this method you only can covert in your case binary into an integer.

So if you try:
parseInt("10101",2) the result would be 21. And this is correct. But in your case you provide to the method absolute invalid arguments because you may only use 0 and 1 for a binary input. The conversion goes left to right. The first invalid value will force to return the result without further compute.

Your 1st case:
parseInt('123',2)
The number 2 is an invalid binary value. This will make to finish after the 1 as input, which is a 1 as integer. It is correct.

Your 2nd try:
parseInt('123', 3)

The last number 3 is invalid for a base of 3 with 0,1,2 as valid numbers. And if you convert the number 12 with the base of 3 the result is 5. From my point of view the method works as expected.

Comment: This is JavaScript, it's not `Integer.parseInt()` it's just `parseInt()`.

Comment: Typo. But no matter what language :) This method works like a charm